# AnimatedContainer behaving different for different child

Tags: flutter, dart

`AnimatedContainer` doesn't seem to work for `Container` and works fine for `FlutterLogo`, why is that so?

---

**Code:**

```
bool _value = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var flutterLogo = FlutterLogo(size: _value ? 400 : 200, colors: Colors.blue,);
  var container = Container(height: _value ? 400 : 200, color: Colors.blue,);

  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => setState(() => _value = !_value),
    ),
    body: AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      child: container, // putting flutterLogo here works fine
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**PS:**

I know there exist `height` property in `AnimatedContainer` which solves the issue, but I want to know why normal `Container` `height` fails here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AnimatedContainer` does not animate when the size of its child change. If no `height`/`width` is specified, it takes the size of its child instead.

The fact that it works for `FlutterLogo` is completely unrelated to `AnimatedContainer`. It is `FlutterLogo` that animate its size.